# Facing SQL performance issues when the filter values are changed for date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, business-objects

The SQL Query is showing the performance issues when the filter values for the date are changed.

For example,

This SQL is taking too long to fetch results(mm/dd/yyyy),

```
Select * from table_A where date between '12/31/2014' and '01/31/2015'
```

Whereas, this same SQL with filter values changed, fetching the results much faster.

```
Select * from table_A where date between '11/30/2014' and '01/31/2015'
```

However, in the second SQL, the date range is increased, so logically, it should take more time.

The data type is `datetime`. We used single quotes, as this is a generated SQL from SAP BO Report.

Can anyone elaborate the cause behind this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this within a stored procedure? If so are the dates params?

Comment: @AlexK., it is a simple SQL fetching data from no. of tables.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the data type is datetime. We used single quotes, as this is a generated SQL from SAP BO Report.

Comment: Doesn't '11/31/2014' raise an error?!?

Comment: I would recommend to **always** use the **ISO-8601** date format when specifying dates as string literals. Use `yyyymmdd` for your dates to be independent of any SQL Server settings (like language and regional settings).

Comment: @jarlh, '11/31/2014'  does not raise an error.

Comment: @marc_s unfortunately, we can not change the existing table structure for this issue.

Comment: Compare execution plans and statistics io/time and possible wait-stats for the two queries. Chances are you have bad indexes/look up due to not using correct datatypes, but we'll need more information to help guide it. I - like above - also struggle with understanding how you can have 31 days in November if indeed is datetime datatype anywhere in the flow?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, it was mistake. Corrected Nov to 30. I will try if i could share the execution plan. One dumb question in mind, if the issue is related to indexes, then why making difference between two dates ? Fyi, indexing is done on the column.

Comment: Check the plans for the two different queries. Also, check the counts of the number of records 1) for the entire table 2) for Jan 2015, and 3) for Dec 2014 and Jan 2015.  It could be the first query is trying to use an index when a scan maybe more appropriate and the second query is just doing a scan. For example, if the result is returning 10% of the rows of the table, it probably doesn't make sense to use an index.

Comment: You don't need change any table structure - just your **queries!** Use `where date between '20141130' and '20150131'` instead of what you're been using so far.....

Comment: Using between operator with dates is not a good idea. It will leave out any such record for January 31st where time > 00:00:00

Comment: @JamesZ, the SQL is generated SQL by Infoview (SAP BO). So unfortunately can not change it. I need only the reason why it takes the time. Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s, its a generated SQL. Please see above comment. I am ok with the cause of delay also. Not needed solution. Thanks.